# Парсинг текста различных тегов по порядку с помощью JSOUP

Tags: java, алгоритм, jsoup

Допустим у меня имеется html код:

```
<h2 class="song">I Like It</h2>
<span class="artist">Cardi B</span>

<h2 class="song">Sad!</h2>
<a class="artist">XXXTENTACION</a>

<h2 class="song">Lucid Dreams</h2>
<span class="artist">Juice WRLD</span>

<h2 class="song">Girls Like You</h2>
<span class="artist">Maroon 5 Featuring Cardi B</span>

<h2 class="song">Nice For What</h2>
<a class="artist">Drake</a>
```

Я могу пропарсить названия треков:

```
Document docTracks = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();
Elements newsHeadlines = docTracks.select("h2");
List<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element element :newsHeadlines ){
    songs.add(element.text());
}
songs.toString();
```

Загвоздка заключается в тегах(`span` и `a`) с рандомным расположением, которые следуют после тегов `h2`. Как я могу получить имена исполнителей в соответствии с треками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась методом JSOUP `getElementsByAttributeValue`

```
Elements newsHeadlines1 = docTracks.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "artist");
```